# Как изменить GDB в CLion?

Tags: c++, отладка, clion, gdb

Написал код под AVR (atmega8p), скомпилировал в elf и hex файлы. При нажатии кнопки `debug` выдаёт сообщение:

```
com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Cannot determine architecture of the target: elf32-little
Process finished with exit code 0`
```

Полагаю он пытается использовать встроенный gdb и не видит в `.elf` файле нужной архитектуры. Как настроить CLion, чтобы он использовал `avr-gdb.exe`? 
Пусть условно он находится по пути `c:\AVR-Toolchain\AVR8\bin\avr-gdb.exe`

Может что-то в CMakeList прописать надо? Компиляторы там указывал с помощью `set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER PathToCompilerC)` и `set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER PathToCompilerCpp)`

Comment: наверно File - Settings - Build, Execution, Deployment - Toolchains

Answer (score 0):

Нужно в настройках Clion создать кастомный Toolchain.

Preferences->Build,Execution,Deployment->Toolchains

При создании есть возможность указать пути к Cmake, компилятору и дебагеру.

Comment: пробовал, но CLion не признаёт дебаггер указанный в тех настройках.